# Angular2 value of variable in subsrcibe is undefined

Tags: angular, undefined, subscribe

Good morning,

I have the following problem:

```
onSubmit(){ 
  this.userService.getCandidate(this.candidate)
    .subscribe( 
      (candidate) => { 
        this.candidate2 = candidate;
        console.log(this.candidate2);
        this.name=this.candidate.name;
        console.log(this.candidate2.name);
      },
      (error: Response) =>  console.log(error),
      ()=> {
            console.log("Finished")}
      )
}
```

`console.log(this.candidate2);` gives me the expected candidate with all the fields
but `console.log(this.candidate2.name);` give me undefined.

What should I do because I the value of the different fields of a candidate.

Comment: What is this candidate ?? it's model

Comment: can you update candidate and this.candidate values in question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually errors is from this line

```
 this.name=this.candidate.name;
```

change it as

```
this.name=this.candidate2.name;
```

or

```
this.name=candidate.name;
```

It should be,

```
onSubmit(){ 
  this.userService.getCandidate(this.candidate)
    .subscribe( 
      (candidate) => { 
        this.candidate2 = candidate;
        console.log(this.candidate2);
        this.name=this.candidate2.name;
        console.log(this.candidate2.name);
      },
      (error: Response) =>  console.log(error),
      ()=> {
            console.log("Finished")}
      )
}
```

Comment: or this.name = candidate.name.

Comment: Oups, Havn't seen. My bad!

Comment: I test it but don't know why I still get undefined

Comment: what do you see when you console.log(this.candidate2)

Comment: I obtain Array(1) with all the field of candidate with correct value.

Comment: if its an array then you should access using  this.name=this.candidate2[0].name; or  console.log(this.candidate2[0].name);